# Google Analytics API Python quickstart

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to get some data out of Google Analytics.
On step 3.3 on the quickstart guide is written to replace the value of SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL. 
The problem is that I cant find the variable SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL. Neither in the client_secrets.json file nor in the HelloAnalytics.py file.

Any ideas?

Guide: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the JSON file with the key "client_email" (at least in all my key files), and you should find it in the "IAM and admin" section of the API console (or Cloud console as it is apparently called now).

However you do not need to enter this anywhere. This is a typo, or a holdover from a previous version of the API. The analytics module will take the email address from the json file.

Comment: in the json file is already a linie "client mail" with an address  like XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com. there is nothing to change or?

Comment: Curse me for not reading your question properly. I think the reference to the email address is a holdover from the documentation for the p12 key files. My python scripts run fine without entering the mail address anywhere. I have updated the answer accordingly.