# Issues with sample HelloAnalytics.py from Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

Google's [sample code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#3_setup_the_sample) on the [official Quickstart Webpage](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py) is outdated and does not work.

As [Google encourages to use StackOverflow](https://developers.google.com/analytics/help/), I am not only hoping for help with the following issues, but to **motivate Google to update their sample code**.

- I pip installed google-api-python-client (without sudo, [btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421857/why-sudo-pip-install-if-pip-install-works-issues-with-helloanalytics-py)).
- There is no `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` anymore ([for years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916648/google-analytics-api-python-quickstart)).
- As `KEY_FILE_LOCATION` I entered the name of the JSON-file. Is that what you mean by "appropriate values from the Developer Console"?
- I fixed the print functions in line 65, 68 and 70 (which also [confused others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493828/google-reporting-api-v4-issue), especially since Python 2.7 is [deprecated](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#deprecated-python-versions) for google-api-python-client).

If I run that, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ralf/code/test_snippets/20-06-17_google_analytics_api/HelloAnalytics.py", line 4, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'
```

So obviously, there is missing an import. [oauth2client](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/) is deprecated and they recommend [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [oauthlib](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**How can I get this working?** Every hint is welcome and Google, please, fix that sample code to save others from frustrating and tedious research.

Thanks!

Comment: You linked the one for service accounts is the one for installed applications off as well? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py     I have pinged the team about the sample needing updating thanks for the report.

Comment: My google contact says thanks again and keep any eye out the new version should go live tomrrow

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but as far as I can see [there](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#3_setup_the_sample) is still the old version online. Would you please be so kind to ask your contact again? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The sample code has been updated by Google now (thanks to [DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)) and looks as follows:

```
"""Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range:', str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)


def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Unfortunately, I still get an error:

```
Exception has occurred: HttpError
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.">
  File "/Users/ralf/code/test_snippets/20-07-01_google_analytics_api/HelloAnalytics.py", line 42, in get_report
    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
  File "/Users/ralf/code/test_snippets/20-07-01_google_analytics_api/HelloAnalytics.py", line 75, in main
    response = get_report(analytics)
  File "/Users/ralf/code/test_snippets/20-07-01_google_analytics_api/HelloAnalytics.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
```

I followed the steps as described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#3_setup_the_sample) carefully, especially [Create Credentials](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#create_credentials) and [Add service account to the Google Analytics account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#add_service_account_to_the_google_analytics_account), but obviously something went wrong. I will try it again later.